# How to check if record has matching parts for given criteria in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel

I have not managed to figure out how to solve a problem I am facing at the moment.

I have certain records in my DB table - study groups to be specific. Such as **IK15**, **IK16**, **TEK15**, **TEK17** and so on. Well basically the first part, the letters in that case remain the same, but the number after them is different and will change after some time.

I need to create a condition which would check whether the record meets the criteria. But it should only check the first part of the record, the letters in this case.

So it should return **true** for **IK11**, **IK14** **IK12**, **IK19** (checks if record contains "IK") and **false** for everything else that's different.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: So, checking for `IS` within `IK11`, `IK14`, ... would return `false`. Is that a typo? Also, are these their own columns or values within a single column?

Comment: Yes it was a typo, my bad. And yes, they are values in a single column.

Comment: So lets say we have groups such as IK12, TEK11, IK17, KS14. It should only return true for groups with "IK" in them. Since the numbers after the letters are different and will change overtime.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear, but from what I am gathering, you could use regular expressions for this? For example, the following matches anything that starts with "IK" and is followed by numbers.

`IK[0-9]*$`

This would match strings like `IK33` `IK11` `IK19` but not match `IK19a`

Comment: Are you suggesting that this be done in PHP? It's probably much more efficient to do it in the database.

Answer (score 0):

As the values are in a single column, you can use a `LIKE` operator to check if the column (`VARCHAR`) contains something like `IK`:

```
$results = \DB::table("table")->where("study_groups", "LIKE", "%IK%")->get();
```

So for your examples of

```
// Study Groups Column
"IK15, IK16, TEK15, TEK17"; // true (`IK15`, `IK16`)
"IK12, TEK11, IK17, KS14";  // true (`IK12` and `IK17`)
"IK11, IK14 IK12, IK19"; // true (all values)
```

The `LIKE` operator is pretty open-ended, meaning if it finds `IK` *anywhere* in the column, it will return that row.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got it working now the way I wanted.

I ended up stripping the numbers from the string and then comparing it with specific record and then returning either false or true based on whether it's equal to comparable record.

I guess my question was badly formatted and hard to understand thus I apologize for that.